# linq 'where' and 'or' operator

Tags: c#, linq

i have a multiple result for a result view, now i am currently try to define a linq statement which contains multiple unknown value with 'or' operator.

This is how i do

```
            for (int b = 0; b < result3.Count(); b++)
            {
                int value = result3[b].category_id;
                query4 = query4.Where(p => p.category_id == value ).OrderBy(p => p.sort_order);
                tempData.Add(value);
            }
```

However, what is the outcome is, this is the 'and' clause, i want to create a 'or' operator, it is possible?

Comment: i think i should use the keyword of 'operator'

Comment: You would need to build up an Expression, and then apply it once. It would probably be easier to use something like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No explicit loop required here

```
  var ids = result3.Where(x => x.category_id);
  query4 = query4.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.category_id))
  tempData = query4.Select(z => z.category_id)
                   .OrderBy(c => c.sort_order);
```

This will probably give you the "OR" output expected in the loop. However the *tempData* variable contains exactly the same values extracted in the *var ids* but just sorted, so, if *result3* and *query4* are enumerables of the same type T then you can setup *tempData* before the *query4* and use it to filter query4.

```
  var tempData = result3.Where(x => x.category_id)
                        .OrderBy(c => c.sort_order)
                        .Select(p => p.category_id);
  query4 = query4.Where(x => tempData.Contains(x.category_id))
```

Comment: yeah i think this is the answer